# Next image doesnt work when page content updated by infinite-scroll

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, fancybox-3

I use fancybox 3 and infinite sctoll. All works fine when I scroll down. But if I open 1 image and press next buttons, items that loaded by `$infScroll.infiniteScroll('loadNextPage');` are on page, but at the end of current page next images will not open by next button. If close current popup and open again a can go next again before next page. Why dynamically added items not works by next button?

```
$('.gallery').fancybox({
    selector : ".img-box",
    ...
    ,
    afterShow: function(instance, item){
        if (item.index  >=  instance.group.length - 10) {
            $infScroll.infiniteScroll('loadNextPage');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding/removing items from the page would not automatically affect currently open fancybox gallery. You would need to update gallery manually -

```
// Call `createGroup` with collection of fresh links 
$.fancybox.getInstance().createGroup( $('.img-box')  );

// Update controls
$.fancybox.getInstance().updateControls();
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but not well. Strange but, after this instance.group contains starter kit of elements +  starter kit +new elements. Example:
<item1>
<item2>
<item3>
..added new elements.
instance.group = 
<item1>
<item2>
<item3>
<item1>
<item2>
<item3>
<item4>
<item5>
<item6>
And in html page starts elemets NOT doubled. And if close fancybox gallery and open again all works fine.

Comment: You should replace $('.img-box') with "collection of fresh links", because "createGroup" method adds elements to current group.

Comment: I'm glad I found this as I was also confused by the "dynamic" wording in the selector documentation.

Is 'createGroup' the right thing with the current version (3.5.7)? I can't find it in the source code, but I find an 'addContent' function, which seems to do the right now (including calling updateControls).

Comment: Yes, that is right, you can use `addContent` method now. "dynamic" is not the same thing you might expect from vue/react, it means that the script is simply attaching click event to selector so that it will work for items added in the future, too.